# Monkey patching the watir-classic method not working

Tags: ruby, watir, monkeypatching

In watir-classic gem, we have a method called generate_ruby_code() under Element class. I would like to monkey patch it and modify few things.

What I did is:

### MyFile.rb

---

```rb
require 'watir-classic'
module Watir
    class Element
        def generate_ruby_code(element, method_name, *args)
            puts "Print this"
        end
    end
end
```

But instead of calling my monkey patched method, the original generate_ruby_code in the Element class is called everytime which I don't want to happen.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: can you show the code from where the method has been called?

Comment: Originally the generate_ruby_code() method is called from method_missing() on the same class. So when I call click_no_wait() method, the method_missing() is called and in turn the generate_ruby_code() is called.

Comment: But still show us the part of the code,from where the method is being called... Let me see..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

I assume that you are using watir-classic v3.7.0 or older.

In these versions, doing `require 'watir-classic'` does not load all of the classes immediately. Some of the classes, including the Watir::Element, are not loaded until a browser instance is created.

This means that:

```
# Does not create Watir::Element#generate_ruby_code yet
require 'watir-classic'

# You create a Watir::Element#generate_ruby_code method
module Watir
    class Element
        def generate_ruby_code(element, method_name, *args)
            puts "Print this"
        end
    end
end

# Watir loads the Watir::Element#generate_ruby_code, which overrides yours
browser = Watir::Browser.new
```

My understanding is that this is due tp watir-classic previously supporting multiple browsers - ie FireWatir and SafariWatir. Various classes were autoloaded based on the browser being used.

**Solution 1 - Upgrade to v4.0 or later**

The easiest solution is to upgrade your watir-classic to v4.0 or later (current latest is 4.0.1).

The autoloading was removed in this version, which means your code will now work as is.

**Solution 2 - Initialize browser first**

If upgrading is not an option, you need to manually force the autoload before monkey patching. You can do this by simply referencing the constant with:

```
Watir::IE
```

Simply include this at some point after requiring watir-classic and before monkey patching.

```
require 'watir-classic'
Watir::IE # this will load the code

module Watir
    class Element
        def generate_ruby_code(element, method_name, *args)
            puts "Print this"
        end
    end
end

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'www.google.ca'
browser.link.click_no_wait
#=> "Print this"
```

Comment: 1st solution may not be the best option considering my current environment at my work area. But the 2nd solution worked like a charm. Thanks Justin Ko.

Comment: By the way - you do not need to open a new IE window at all, but just need to trigger the autoload mechanism. You can do that by just referencing the constant itself like this: `require "watir-classic"; Watir::IE # this will load the code`

Comment: Thanks @JarmoPertman, I did not know that. The answer has been updated.

Comment: People those who will work under you, they will learn a lot... I miss the workplace, where you are working!

Answer (score 0):

Look, I do not know what exactly is happening in your case, but you can safely rule out Ruby malfunctioning. Here are a couple of hints what you can do:

```
# Assuming that your element of class Watir::Element is stored in variable x:

x.method( :generate_ruby_code ).owner # will give you the owning module

x.method( :generate_ruby_code ).source_location # will give you the place where the method is,
# that is going to be used when you send x the message :generate_ruby_code

x.class # will confirm that your object indeed is what you think it is

x.singleton_class.ancestors # will give you the full method lookup chain for x
```

With this, you shoul be equipped to uncover why your expectations for x's behavior are not met.